# Not enough swap space to hibernate?

Tags: virtualbox, suspend, hibernate, swap, dbus

It seems that I have enough though; maybe it's not automatic swap mounting?

Any help on getting hibernate working is appreciated.

[image: Problem]

Comment: What is not hibernating the host or the virtualbox guest ? How much RAM do you have ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add more swap easily so that I can hibernate my laptop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/49095/how-do-i-add-more-swap-easily-so-that-i-can-hibernate-my-laptop)

Comment: This is **not** a dupe to the swap question as here a virtual machine needs to be hibernated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a good idea to hibernate your Virtual Box virtual machine to the virtual disk swap. The appropriate way to achieve hibernation is to close your virtual machine with *Machine -> Close* (or just close the virtual machine window):

[image]

Choose **"Save the machine state"** for "hibernating" to a file on your host partition.

You can also do this from command line **on the host** with the following command:

```
VBoxManage controlvm <name> savestate
```

Replace `<name>` by the name of your VM.